# composer install fails trying to get own typo3 extension hosted on bitbucket

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I have a TYPO3 extension hosted on bitbucket. I would like to get this extension with composer. As I understood, there must be a composer.json in my extension root and there must be some entries in my composer.json which i run composer install

composer.json of my extension

```
{
  "name": "vendor/extkey",
  "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
  "description": "Extension for bla bla bla",
  "keywords": [],
  "homepage": "http://www.vendor.com",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "blah",
      "email": "dev@vendor.com",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "version": "2016",
  "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^7.6.0"
    }
}
```

composer.json which i run composer update:

```
{
  "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://user@bitbucket.org/path/extension.git"
        }
    ],
  "name": "blah",
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms": "7.6.2",
    "bk2k/bootstrap-package" : "dev-master",
    "path/extension": "2016"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
      "web-dir": "web"
    },
    "installer-paths": {
            "typo3conf/ext/{$name}": ["vendor/package"]
        }

  }
}
```

I get always an error:
The requested package path/extension could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Does somebody has a working example?

Comment: I'm not sure if Composer respects the `version` entry from composer.json when installing the package from a Git repository. Do you have a `2016` tag in your repository? If not, try creating one.

Comment: I suppose, my local composer does even not find the one hosted at bitbucket. The error 'The requested package path/extension could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name' points me on that.

Comment: I'm asking about the tag because Compose will not install unstable versions (i.e branches; stable versions are tags) by default. Might be the issue here.

Comment: Oh, and are the `name` (in your example `vendor/extkey`) from the extensions composer.json and the the `require`'d package name in the project composer.json (in your example `path/extension`) the same value?

Comment: 2016 is a branch. Now require (project) and name (extension) are matching but still the same issue.

Comment: When installing a branch, try using `dev-<branchname>` as version specifier. Meaning `dev-2016` in this case.

Comment: This is working! YES! just the last part to "checkout" in another location is not working yet. This should be done like "installer-paths": {
            "vendor/package": "{$web-dir}/typo3conf/ext/"
        }

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'll wrap all this up in an answer so that you can close this question, ok?

Comment: may I link to this question regarding the path where the checkout is going to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808337/composer-installs-own-typo3-extension-in-wrong-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The requested package `<insert-package-key-here>` could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

This message means that the version that you're requesting Composer to install does not exist in the registered repository. Now, when requiring a package from a Git repository, Composer will use the tags and branches from that repository for its versioning information.

As you have required your extension as `"vendor/extKey": "2016"`, Composer will look for a tag named `2016` in your repository.

You stated in comments that you have a *branch* named `2016` instead. When requiring a branch, you will need to use `dev-<branch>` as version specifier in your `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/extKey": "dev-2016"
}
```

Alternatively, create a tag in your repository and use that as version in your `composer.json`.

See also the [Composer manual](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags) on this (emphasis mine):

> #### Tags
>
> **For every tag that looks like a version, a package version of that tag will be created.** It should match 'X.Y.Z' or 'vX.Y.Z', with an optional suffix of -patch (-p), -alpha (-a), -beta (-b) or -RC. The suffix can also be followed by a number.
>
> #### Branches
>
> For every branch, a package development version will be created. If the branch name looks like a version, the version will be `{branchname}-dev`. For example, the branch 2.0 will get the 2.0.x-dev version (the .x is added for technical reasons, to make sure it is recognized as a branch). The 2.0.x branch would also be valid and be turned into 2.0.x-dev as well. **If the branch does not look like a version, it will be `dev-{branchname}`. `master` results in a `dev-master` version.**