# composer installs own TYPO3 extension in wrong path

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I have a own TYPO3 extension hosted on bitbucket. Getting this via composer works ([see here for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769510/composer-install-fails-trying-to-get-own-typo3-extension-hosted-on-bitbucket)). The extension is downloaded into my vendor folder. Being there i cannot install the extension via extension-manager.

How can I getting my ext into typo3conf/ext (ensuring autoloading will work)?

The extensions coming via

```
{
"type": "composer",
"url": "http://composer.typo3.org/"
}
```

are going to (as expected):

```
web/typo3config/ext
```

here is my project composer.json:

```
{
  "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "metaxos/exaibbrplus",
                "version": "dev-2016",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://metaxos@bitbucket.org/metaxos/exaibbrplus.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "release/2016"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
  "name": "Metaxos/ibbrating2016",
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms": "7.6.2",
    "bk2k/bootstrap-package" : "dev-master",
    "typo3-ter/compatibility6" : "7.6.0",
    "typo3-ter/extension-builder" : "7.6.0",
    "metaxos/exaibbrplus": "dev-2016"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
      "web-dir": "web"
    }
  }
}
```

here is my extension composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "metaxos/exaibbrplus",
  "description": "custom ext for typo3",
  "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": ">=7.6.0,<8.0"
  },
  "replace": {
    "extkey": "self.version",
    "typo3-ter/extkey": "self.version"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Metaxos\\Exaibbrplus\\": "Classes/"
    }
  },
  "keywords": ["custom", "ext"],
  "homepage": "http://www.blah.ch"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `type` key with the value `typo3-cms-extension` to the root `composer.json`. This will place your extension in `web/typo3conf/ext` instead of `vendor/$vendor/$package` which in turn will make it available to the cms.

It is important, to know that if you redefine the package in the root composer.json as `repository` type `package`, **nothing** from the extensions' `composer.json` file will be taken into account and you need to define any concerns about that package in the root `composer.json`.

So-applying the rules I mentioned above, your root `composer.json` will look like that:

`{
  "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://composer.typo3.org/"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "metaxos/exaibbrplus",
                "version": "dev-2016",
                "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://metaxos@bitbucket.org/metaxos/exaibbrplus.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "release/2016"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-4": {
                        "Metaxos\\Exaibbrplus\\": "Classes/"
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    ],
  "name": "Metaxos/ibbrating2016",
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms": "7.6.2",
    "bk2k/bootstrap-package" : "dev-master",
    "typo3-ter/compatibility6" : "7.6.0",
    "typo3-ter/extension-builder" : "7.6.0",
    "metaxos/exaibbrplus": "dev-2016"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
      "web-dir": "web"
    }
  }
}`

As mentioned above by @helmbert, you are either left with completely redefining the package or using another repository type. You may want to consider using satis or a URL repository.

Comment: @Cedirc YES! That was the missing part. I had this only in the extension composer.json. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For Composer to install the package in `web/typo3conf/ext`, the package needs to have the type `typo3-cms-extension`. In your extension's `composer.json` this type is actually declared, however Composer will not respect it because you explicitly declare the package configuration in your project-level `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
  # ...
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "metaxos/exaibbrplus",
      "version": "dev-2016",
      "source": {
        "url": "https://metaxos@bitbucket.org/metaxos/exaibbrplus.git",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "release/2016"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As you're using `"type": "package"` for your own repository, I suspect that Composer ignores the `composer.json` from that package. As you already have a Git repository that contains a `composer.json`, I'd suggest adding the repository using the [`vcs` type](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) instead:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://metaxos@bitbucket.org/metaxos/exaibbrplus.git"
  }
]
```

When doing that, Composer should use the composer.json from that repository, recognize the correct package type (`typo3-cms-extension`) and install the package in the correct directory.

Comment: using `"type" : "vcs"` brings  The requested package metaxos/exaibbrplus could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name. Stil using `"metaxos/exaibbrplus": "dev-2016"` for the branch in require.

Comment: In your question you're now using `release/2016` as branch name, but are still requiring `dev-2016`. So which branch name are you actually using, `2016` or `release/2016`?

Comment: I still require dev-2016, the release/2016 of the package block is removed, please [see here](http://pastebin.com/2rgnKQ1P)

Comment: You may have to move your autoload information to your root composer.json to actually get your classes loaded. You can read more about TYPO3 7 LTS and composer here: https://usetypo3.com/typo3-and-composer.html

Comment: @Daniel but, if I don't miss something, I still need to have the ext in typo3conf/ext to be able to install the ext via EM

Answer (score 0):

try to add

`"replace": {
    "exaibbrplus": "self.version",
    "typo3-ter/exaibbrplus": "self.version"
  },`

And use only `"Metaxos\\Exaibbrplus\\": "Classes/"` in the autoloader.

Comment: sorry, I copied a old composer.json. I took your input already in consideration, still going in vendor. Code in question is up-to-date now.